# How can I play video clips according to a list?

Tags: python, video, video-streaming, video-processing, video-capture

An example of video files:

```
v1.rmvb
v2.rmvb
v3.rmvb
...
```

An example of a playlist (from csv files or database):

```
Order    File_Name      Play_Time
1        v1.rmvb        00:00:10 --> 00:00:15
2        v3.rmvb        00:18:45 --> 00:19:10
3        v2.rmvb        00:01:40 --> 00:02:00
4        v3.rmvb        01:20:15 --> 01:20:29
...
```

I would like to only play a short clip (around 20 to 30 seconds) from each video, and the playlist may be long (from a few to several hunderd). I wrote a program with moviepy to save clips as independent files and it works. However, it take too much time and storage. Now I am thinking about PyQt, but is there any easier ways to approach this?